# Determine whether L1 and L2 intersect. If so, find the point of intersection Q.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**Problem:** Let *L1* be the line passing through the points ***Q1* = (4, 3, 1)** and ***Q2* = (5, 1, −1)** and let *L2* be the line passing through the point ***P1* = (−7, 15, −7)** with direction vector ***→d*=<−4, 4, −4>**. Determine whether *L1* and *L2* intersect. If so, find the point of intersection *Q*.

I think I am attempting this problem wrong. I first get *L1* by doing *Q1* + *t(Q2)*, which gives me **<5t + 4, t + 3, -t + 1>** and get *L2* by doing *L2* + *→d* = **<-4d - 7, 4d + 15, -4d -7>**

After this, I just solved for *t* and *d*, and plugged in the values for *L1* and *L2*, but I get the wrong answer on every variant of this question. Can anyone help guide me through this?

Comment: The equation of the line through points $\vec A,\vec B$ is $\vec{r}=t\vec{A}+(1-t)\vec{B}$, not $\vec A+t\vec B$.

Comment: Okay, so then I get *L1* = **<-t + 5, 2t + 1, 2t - 1>**. Afterwards, solving for t and d gave me t = 1, d = -3. Plugging both these values in gives me two different arrays, however the answer states the lines are supposed to intersect.

Comment: You haven't solved the simultaneous equations correctly.  You have $(-t+5,2t+1,2t-1)=(-4d-7,4d+15,-4d-7)$, in particular, $-t+5=-4d-7=2t+1$ which gives $t=2$ and hence the corresponding $d=-\frac52$.  Now check the $y$-component.

Comment: Yes, you're answer is right, I messed up in solving the equations. t = 2 and d = -5/2 gives the following intersection at point ***Q* = (3, 5, 3)**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the equation of your second line to find a mistake in the direction vector.

Hopefully that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are not correct. you need to define parametric equations such that when it is 0, then you get the initial point. In this case then, your parametric equation will be:

for line L1: where **t** is the vector Q2-Q1

- x-4=t
- y-3=-2t
- z-1-2t

As for L2:

- x+7=-4d
- y-15=4d
- z+7=-4d

in general the parametric equation of a line is

- x-x(naught)=t*v(sub x)
- y-y(naught)=t*v(sub y)
- z-z(naught)=t*v(sub z)

where x,y,z (naught) are x,y, and z components of the point give. 
v(sub x,y,z) are the x, y, and z components of the direction vector.